# Power Set and Union

Tags: math, modeling, powerset

Following set is given:

```
X := {Horse, Dog} 
Y := {Cat}
```

I define the set:

```
M := Pow(X) u {Y}
```

**u** for union

The resulting set of the power set operation is:

```
Px := {0, {Horse}, {Dog}, {Horse, Dog}}
```

**0** for empty set

My question is referenced to the unio operation. **How do I unite 0 and Y?**

```
M := {{Horse, Cat}, {Dog, Cat}, {Horse, Dog, Cat}}
```

Comment: Is this about `Mathematica` the programming language or mathematics?

Comment: It is a subject called modelling, used to describe problems...and mathematics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have

```
M := Pow(X) u {Y}
```

with

```
Pow(X) := {0, {Horse}, {Dog}, {Horse, Dog}}
```

so

```
M := {0, {Horse}, {Dog}, {Horse, Dog}} u {{Cat}}
```

Does that clear it up for you?

The set you've displayed the union mapped over the cartesian product and missing `{Cat}`.

Comment: Hm, but cat has to be added to the other elements since it is a union!? like M := {{Horse, Cat}, {Dog, Cat}, {Horse, Dog, Cat}} or is that wrong?

Comment: @ArtWordAD, It's the union of the set Pow(X) with {Cat}. It's Not the union of {Cat} with each individual element of Pow(X) which is what you are trying to do. Do you see the distinction?

Comment: so what would be the resulting set of M := {0, {Horse}, {Dog}, {Horse, Dog}} u {Cat}?

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, I think it would help you to replace Pow(X) with elements that are not sets and take the union of that set with {Cat} to see how it works. You can then substitute the elements of the replacement set for the corresponding elements of Pow(X) in the union and you will have your answer. Another alternative would be to review the definition of the union of two sets and look for a corner case in it where one of the sets contains sets. [hint: you won't find it]

Comment: thanks, so M := {0, {Horse}, {Dog}, {Horse, Dog}, Cat} would be the final set?

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, we both made a mistake but andand caught it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to differ slightly with the other responses.  If you define `Y = {Cat}` then `{Y} = {{Cat}}`, that is, `Y` is the set containing the element `Cat` and `{Y}` is the set containing `Y`, or the set containing the set containing the element `Cat`.  In that case:

```
M := {0, {Horse}, {Dog}, {Horse, Dog}, {Cat} }
```

It's a subtle, but important distinction in set theory.

Comment: There's not actually much subtlety about it

Answer (score 1):

```
M := {0, {Horse}, {Dog}, {Horse, Dog}, Cat}
```

The definition of the union is the set of elements that are in either set. So `{Horse,Cat}` is not in the union, because it is not in either set.